# Tikz Poster - Aligning titlegraphic to the right of the title

Tags: positioning, titles, posters, tikzposter

I would like to create a poster title, with a logo right-aligned, rather than on top of the title text. What I have is:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Desert}

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions in Typed Text} 
\author{AdamG} 
\institute{Graduate Center}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{GCLogo.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How can I change the logo's alignment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Desert}

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions in Typed Text}
\author{AdamG}
\institute{Graduate Center}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
   \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
       \centering
       \@titlegraphic
    \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please make fine adjustments like the width of `minipage`s to suit your taste.

## Edit:

You make make the title centered by this way:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Desert}

\title{Detecting Multi-word Expressions in Typed Text}
\author{AdamG}
\institute{Graduate Center}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[scale=0.8,anchor=east,xshift=0.56\linewidth,yshift=3.9cm,inner sep=0pt] {%
       \@titlegraphic
    };
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Again, fine adjustments may be made as per the needs.

Comment: I think this could also be done calling `\settitle`

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro: `\settitle` also uses `\renewcommand\TP@maketitle` internally.